# Module not found Error : Can't resolve './ ' in Angular8

Tags: angular8

**ERROR in ./src/app/list-emp/list-emp.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ ' in 'E:\angular\Assignments\CrudExampleNodejs\Assign4\src\app\list-emp'**

MY list-emp.ts is as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';  
import { Employee } from '../app.module';  
import { Router } from "@angular/router";  

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-list-emp',  
  templateUrl: './list-emp.component.html',  
  styleUrls: [' ']  
})  
export class ListEmpComponent implements OnInit {  

  employees: Employee[];  

  constructor(private empService: EmployeeService, private router: Router, ) { }  

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.empService.getEmployees()  
      .subscribe((data: Employee[]) => {  
        this.employees = data;  
      });  
  }  
  deleteEmp(employee: Employee): void {  
    this.empService.deleteEmployees(employee.id)  
      .subscribe(data => {  
        this.employees = this.employees.filter(u => u !== employee);  
      })  
  }  
  editEmp(employee: Employee): void {  
    localStorage.removeItem('editEmpId');  
    localStorage.setItem('editEmpId', employee.id.toString());  
    this.router.navigate(['add-emp']);  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this row:

`styleUrls: [' ']`

or add a path to the file with styles.

If you want to write inline styles, change `styleUrls: [' ']` to `styles: ''`

Comment: @RAOMANEESHA if my answer helps you, you can check it as acceptable by clicking the checkbox on the left side.